# How do I retrieve the most frequent text value in a column that has cells with multiple entries in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with data (movie genres in this case) that looks like this:

```
| Drama                     |
| Action, Drama             |
| Action, Adventure, Drama  |
```

I am trying to get the most frequent occurring value, which is 'Drama' in this case.
I came up with the following formula as a beginning but even that doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(UNIQUE(TRIM(SPLIT(A1:A3, ",")))))
```

This returns 0 but I want it to return 3 in this case and then find the most frequent unique value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic case**

`=QUERY(index(if({1,1},TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ",FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")), ", ")))), 
"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc")`

[image]

Notes:

- `transpose` + `split` + `join` is to get the line with all values
- `index` + `if({1,1}...` is to double the column, for query to work. See this trick on [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=594466526).
- `query` is to select the most frequent values on the top.

---

**Get only top value**

use index:

`=index (original_formula, 2, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I get two columns of data but I would only like to display the matching letter for the top value, so 'D' in your example. How would I do that?

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I was trying something similar with index but didn't know the syntax, you edit worked though!